# Random String for transaction code

Tags: php, regex, database, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I would like to ask, I'm developing a website using PHP and currently looking for a better approach.

I want to generate random string for the transaction code.

For example: Customer purchased a product, there must be transaction code to be generated and store it in database table.

Is it better to use a PHP function to generate this then check if transaction code already exists in database table or should I create a stored procedure that will do this? Which do you think is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) in PHP for this

Something like this will do..

```
<?php
echo "TRANSID-".strtoupper(uniqid()); //Generates a random id every time.
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
TRANSID-528B185A2EC6C
```

If you are interested in this have a look [`here`](http://w3resource.com/gallery/creating-unique-ids-with-php-uniqid-function)

Comment: I can also do this with stored procedure, right? Which do you think is faster? Because after generating transaction code, I will check if this transaction code already exists in database table.

Comment: This is a PHP based function and has nothing to do with the backend. The function generates a unique alphanumeric string based on the UNIX timestamp. So 99.9% it will be unique and you can directly push this value to your database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UUID(Universally Unique Identifier), it can be used for any purpose, from user authentication string to payment transaction id.

"SagePay uses similar style string for transaction id"

A UUID is a 16-octet (128-bit) number. In its canonical form, a UUID is represented by 32 hexadecimal digits, displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32 alphanumeric characters and four hyphens).

```
function generate_uuid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0C2f ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x2Aff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffD3 ), mt_rand( 0, 0xff4B )
    );

}
```

//calling funtion

```
$transationID = generate_uuid();
```

some example outputs will be like:

```
51B4DE29-3B71-4FD2-9E6C-071703E1FF31
3777C8C6-9FF5-4C78-AAA2-08A47F555E81
54B91C72-2CF4-4501-A6E9-02A60DCBAE4C
60F75C7C-1AE3-417B-82C8-14D456542CD7
8DE0168D-01D3-4502-9E59-10D665CEBCB2
```

hope it helps someone in future :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating random string will be a speed bottleneck, php can do that. [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is good enough, as it's "based on the current time in microseconds". But conflict is still possible(e.g. you got multiple servers), althouth rarely. So just make it unqiue-index, and if it insert failed, re-try again.